# How do I generate automatic urls for this simple script?

Tags: php

I have a script that automatically loads an image from a directory everytime the page is refreshed. However, if the person wants to link to the image, they cannot, since there are no URLs generated. Here's the current script:

```
<?php
$imagesDir = 'images/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
?>
<img src="http://www.domain.com/<?php echo $randomImage; ?>">
```

As you can see here, the script automatically pulls a random image from the folder then displays it. When the page is refreshed, the script loads a new image. How can I make it so that each image has its own unique URL identifier? Is this even possible? All help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't each image already have its unique URL identifier in that your img src is pointing to said 'unique URL'?

Comment: Yeah each image could be linked directly via image url address. But I am talking about having a static page for each image. Something like http://www.domain.com/image-1.php

Comment: Do you want a php page to go with the image? Or just the image itself?

Comment: Yes, I want a php page to go with the image.

Comment: but what do you want inside the php page? Just the image itself or something extra?

Comment: Just the image itself.

Comment: But why? What's the difference to just linking the url of the image, and creating a php page that contains the image (which basically has the url of the image anyway).

Comment: I want each image to have its own page. Here's the situation. I have a folder with thousands of images. The little script that I posted randomly grabs an image and displays it. When that page is refreshed, another random image is displayed. Rather than creating a page for each image manually, I was wondering if I could do this automatically. I wouldn't know how, which is why I am asking. I know I can just directly link the image, but I would rather want a static page for each image, for comments and social buttons and stuff.

Comment: Ah, now that's a bit different. You don't want JUST the image, but you basically want an html page, with the image as its main theme. There are generally two ways that I can think of off the top of my head. Dynamic generation (which only requires 1 page and a database) or a page for each image. The second method will depend on your OS as I'm only familiar with creating files using linux related OSes.

Comment: The thing is there is no database. There's just the folder with the images and a single php script that randomly displays a random image from the folder.

Comment: how are comments stored then?

Comment: Facebook comments.

Comment: Do you have a template of how you want the image/comments/etc. set up. And do you use linux/mac?

Comment: I'll show you what I mean. http://www.falarious.com - That's the site. I hope this clears up things. Yes I am using Linux.

Comment: And the home page is basically what you want every image page to look like?

Comment: yup basically for now

Comment: I can think of something. I'll write something in the answers, but no guarantees it will work.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your efforts

Comment: Oh and for the line `<img src="http://www.falarious.com/memes/255293_417108891688522_2043156946_n.jpg">` (that's the link to the image) add an id to it, so it'll be easier for the regex I'm thinking of using

Comment: Okay I can do that

Comment: Sounds like you don't want this to be random... you want a page for each image?  (Easily done with PHP by the way... no database needed.)  Can you clarify what you need, specifically?  You want a single URL for all images, with random content each load, or separate URLs for each image?  (Note that you can always have a single URL redirect elsewhere.  This is often a better idea, so that your pages can be cached and searched.)

Comment: Yes a page for each image, but not a static php or html page. I need this to be dynamic. I do not need a single URL for all images. I need a different URL for each image, seperate URLS for each image. I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a way to get parameters into your script.  A common way is with the query string.

```
http://example.com/yourScript.php?image=abcdefg.jpg
```

Then in your PHP script, you can use `$_GET['image']` to determine that requested image was `abcdefg.jpg`.

If that URL doesn't appeal to you, you can configure your web server to rewrite the URL before sending it off to PHP.  That is, you can have something like this:

```
http://example.com/images/abcdefg.html
```

Your web server's rewrite engine will take `/images/abcdefg.html` and rewrite it to `/yourScript.php?image=abcdefg.jpg` internally before sending it to PHP.  The user won't know or care this is happening.  Then you can access the data in your PHP script like normal.

How you do this depends on your web server.  If Apache, you'll want to look into mod_rewrite.  Nginx has the ngx_http_rewrite_module.

Now, in your PHP script, all you have to do is render a page with the correct variable.  I recommend a template engine, but for a simple page, `echo` with `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data will do just fine.  You can do some other things as well such as check for file existence, if you want.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. This is making sense. Can you, if you can, provide sample code on how this can be done?

Comment: @DavidHinojosa For what?  Rewriting?  No, because I don't know what web server you're using.

Comment: I am using Apache. But not for the rewrite, for the $_GET['image'] part

Comment: First, you'll want to verify that the file exists.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php  If it doesn't, you'll want to send a 404 status response.  `http_response_code(404); exit;`  If it does, then just echo it out... `echo '<img src="', htmlspecialchars($_GET['image']), '" />';`  Remember to use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape any arbitrary data for use in an HTML context.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php  If your pages start to get complex, consider a template engine.  http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: Success! I was able to do what I needed to be done with the help of your comments. Check out the result: http://www.falarious.com - As you can see, now each image, with the exception of the first loaded image, can now be directly linked to via URL.